# custom login in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi
 i use login this code in wordpress custom page but it is not working and show the header line 2.i can't understand about this why they show error:Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\deviorce\wp-content\themes\theme11751\header.php:2) in D:\xampp\htdocs\deviorce\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 690

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\deviorce\wp-content\themes\theme11751\header.php:2) in D:\xampp\htdocs\deviorce\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 691

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\deviorce\wp-content\themes\theme11751\header.php:2) in D:\xampp\htdocs\deviorce\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 692

```
$errors = array();
    $user_login = '';
    $user_pass = '';
    $using_cookie = FALSE;
    $_SESSION['your-Email'] = $_POST['log'];
    $_SESSION['your-password'] = $_POST['pwd']; 

    if ( $_POST ) {
    $user_login = $_POST['log'];
    $user_login = sanitize_user($user_login);
    $user_pass  = $_POST['pwd'];

    $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];
    } else {
    $cookie_login = wp_get_cookie_login();
    if (!empty($cookie_login) ) {
        $using_cookie = true;
        $user_login = $cookie_login['login'];
        $user_pass = $cookie_login['password'];
    }
    }
         $result=mysql_query("select user_login,user_pass from wp_users where user_login='$user_login' and user_pass='$user_pass'");
        do_action_ref_array('wp_authenticate', array(&$user_login, &$user_pass));
    if ( $user_login && $user_pass && empty( $errors ) ) {
        $user = new WP_User(0, $user_login);

    if ( wp_login($user_login, $user_pass, $using_cookie) ) {
        if (!$using_cookie)
            wp_setcookie($user_login, $user_pass, false, '', '', $rememberme);
        do_action('wp_login', $user_login); 
        //$_SESSION['step003']="step003";   

        } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='". get_bloginfo('url') ."'</script>";

        }       
    }   
        $user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);

         $userID=$user->ID;
```

kindly help me.advance thanks
Regards
imad

Comment: When you want help on your question, please add all valuable information like error messages. StackOverflow is not a fix-my-code-site ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for that already: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/bm-custom-login/

No sense in reinventing the wheel.